# How to perform upload bandwidth test with youtube before live stream?

Tags: bandwidth, bandwidth-measuring

I understand that it is recommended to perform a bandwidth test before starting a youtube live stream. So that we can select appropriate encode parameters for the stream.

I do know that there are hundreds of services which allow you to perform a bandwidth test(OOKLA, Bandwidthplace etc.) using a browser.

My software runs on an embedded device and I have to do the bandwidth test programmatically, without user intervention.

Currently I have deployed a TCP server which reads and discards data on AWS. I have developed a small bandwidth test client running on my embedded device, which sends data to my server and calculates the bandwidth.

As my bandwidth test is with some other server. The bandwidth that I calculate may not be same as the upload bandwidth I will get with YouTube.

Questions:
1. Is there a service offered by YouTube to check my upload bandwidth before starting live stream ?
2. Are there any better approaches where I can get a good estimate of the current upload bandwidth ?

Answer (score 0):

Just start a "test" live stream and see how it works. Anything else will just be a very rough approximation of the real use case.